# Syntax form create

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to remove this syntax for my form

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            <br>
            {!! $errors->first('name', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('firstname') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">

            {{ Form::label('firstname', 'Student Firstname') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('firstname', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            <br>
            {!! $errors->first('firstname', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}

            {{ Form::submit('Create Student', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block')) }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
```

And put that syntax:

```
 {{csrf_field()}}
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


     <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
       <label for="form-group-input-1">Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('name')}}"/>
       {!! $errors->first('name', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
       </fieldset>

       <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('firstname') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="form-group-input-1">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('firstname')}}"/>
        {!! $errors->first('firstname', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
       </fieldset>
```

Is it a version problem? I am currently with version 5.4.13.

I have to update my version is that right?

Comment: There is no problem because you didn't post one.

Comment: @Bram Verstraten: Ok thank you. is there a command to update laravel?

Comment: Using composer that would be `composer require laravel/framework 5.8.*`. You can check the upgrade documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#upgrade-5.8.0

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem it could be because the Form helper is not included in Laravel anymore since 5.0, as mentioned on [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade).

> The Form and HTML helpers have been deprecated in Laravel 5.0